# Create confirmation pop-up in delete operation

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, jquery-ui

When user click on delete I want to open simple pop-up (which maybe I can extend later on with CSS) which having some text like "Do you want to delete this entry" if user press on "yes" I will invoke the action to delete, if "cancel" then nothing will happen.
How should I do that?

```
 $('#data-table').on('click', '.btnCustomDelete', function () {
            nCurrentDel = $(this).data("id");
```

This is the line of the delete code :

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btnCustomDelete", @data_id = item.Id })
```

Comment: what does query-ui has to do with this..? are you suing something like angular..?

Comment: @TJ-No changed to ASP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `confirm` popup :

```
$('#data-table').on('click', '.btnCustomDelete', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $row = $this.closest("tr"); // row containing this button

    if(confirm("Do you want to delete this entry")) {
        // User has answered "yes", so we remove the current row
        $row.parent().remove($row);
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to style the confirmation popup, you can use jQuery UI dialog.
See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pyLYX/).

The HTML code is the following :

```
<!-- Create the markup for the dialog -->
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
    <p>Do you want to delete this entry?</p>
</div>
```

The javascript is the following :

```
 // "Transform" the dialog-form element into a jQuery UI dialog
 $("#dialog-form").dialog({
     autoOpen: false,  // don't show at startup
     modal: true,      // create as modal (adds an overlay on the page)
     buttons: {        // create the 2 buttons
         Delete: function (evt) {
             // on delete, remove the current row
             $(this).data("row").remove();
             $(this).dialog("close");
         },
         Cancel: function () {
             // on cancel, only close the modal
             $(this).dialog("close");
         }
     }
 });


 // Code to open the modal (called below)
 function openDialog() {
     // here we set the current row into the modal
     $("#dialog-form").data("row", $(this).closest("tr"));

     // open the modal
     $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");         
 }

 // When any element with the class "delete" is clicked, show the modal
 $('#data-table').on('click', '.btnCustomDelete', openDialog);
```

Comment: HI Samuel ,Thanks Voted up,how should I remove the text from the pop-up like "page in local host...want" ?In addtion how should I change the position of the pop-up and the color of it?Thanks!

Comment: You can not remove this text (moreover, it is browser-dependant) and you can not style it, but it is the standard way in order to confirm something (as its name states). But if you want some styling, you can use for example jquery ui dialog (see http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form).

Comment: @mileyH : I have added some sample code with jQuery UI dialog.

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I need (same pop-up style) ,since I new to the web topic can you please show me which are the things that I need to use in order to make it work...

Comment: Thanks but where and how should I call to this dialog?

Comment: With your code, you should use `$('#data-table').on('click', '.btnCustomDelete', openDialog);`, thus anytime you click a button with class `btnCustomDelete` it will call the function openDialog.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55052/discussion-between-mileyh-and-samuel-caillerie).

Answer (score 2):

Using the overload `Html.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object RouteValues, object HtmlAttributes)` and some `javascript`, you can achieve.

Try this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Delete", 
    "Delete", 
    new { id = item.Id }, 
    new { @class = "btnCustomDelete", @data_id = item.Id },
    new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this article?');" }) 
%>
```

This will add the HTML attribute onclick, which will execute the specified javascript when the link is clicked. If an onclick event on a link (or a form's submit button) returns false, the action (following the link, posting the form) doesn't happen. The `confirm(message)` function shows the user a confirmation dialog with the specified message, and returns either true or false depending on the user's response.

The overloaded method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx

**JQuery UI Confirm Dialog:**

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Delete", 
    "Delete", 
    new { id = item.Id }, 
    new { @class = "btnCustomDelete", @data_id = item.Id }) 
%>
```

Javascript/Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        height:180,
    });

    $(".btnCustomDelete").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");

        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
           buttons : {
                     "Confirm" : function() {
                           window.location.href = targetUrl;
                        },
                     "Cancel" : function() {
                           $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
        });

        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
    });
 });
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete the item?" > 
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>This item will be deleted. Are you sure?</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ishan ,Can I do some styling to this pop-up?

Comment: @miley: Accually, this is a simple javascript confirmation box. For styling you should use "JQuery UI Confirm Dialog".

Comment: @mileyH: Please see updated answer. I think, this would help you :)

Comment: Thanks Ishan Voted up,can I add to it CSS?if yes can u provide example?

Comment: When I put the code of the dialog-confirm I got error when I debug it "undefined is not a function" any idea what is wrong?

Comment: @mileyH: Can you please give me the line where you got the error?

Comment: $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({ this is the line when I got the error?

Comment: .dialog() is a extended method of Jquery UI library.  You can not directly use this method.

Comment: so what should I use to make it work,can you please guide me?

Comment: First of all you should read about the jquery plugin from here - http://jqueryui.com/dialog/. (Also see this link http://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/vvjj8/ ).
On http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ Click on "view source" link. For using a plugin you should include the jquery libraries on page head.

Comment: I think that I missing basic thing sine I try to put the code in the script inside the document ready and I got error in the debugger,where should I put this code?

Comment: @mileyH: Yes, you should put your code in "document.ready()". Please see updated answer. :)